# linux wtmp file was enormous

Tags: linux, wtmp

So... I discovered that my wtmp file was really big today, like 2.1GB.

I deleted it and recreated it, but...

Is there any way I can tell logrotate to well, rotate the log?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check `man logrotate`

Logrotate figures out which files need to be rotated based on the settings in /etc/logrotate.conf.

I think the default for wmtp is

```
/var/log/wtmp {
    monthly
    create 0664 root utmp
        minsize 1M
    rotate 1
}
```

If that's not in there, you can add it. If it's not sufficient, you can change it, or add a "size = whatever" directive to tell it to rotate whenever the size exceeds the set value.

Logrotate should be in the `/etc/cron.daily`. If it's not running often enough, you can call `logrotate -f` to force it.

Comment: So, I checked this out, and it all checks out.  I would think a wtmp file of like 2.1GB would be something logrotate will deal with.  And its in /etc/cron.daily.  Nevertheless, thanks for the info satanicpuppy.